# Downloads using any application in terminal results to hanging download

Tags: command-line, 19.10, downloads

When I'm using `docker`, `mvn`, or `wget` for downloading either an image, libraries or just about any file on he net, the download hangs. It's like it's stuck there for some time. The good thing with `docker pull` now, it retries stuck download after a set of time. But in `mvn` or `wget` case most of the time I'll have to repeat the process again.

I would like to know what to do for this, if I need to update, upgrade, install or even reconfigure something on my system. Let me know if you need more info.

I've been scouring the net for an hour now and saw nothing that would solve my issue, in case your have one and I might be using different keywords, please feel free to comment.

Comment: To get an indication where the network problem is; run `$ mtr 8.8.8.8` (or better yet, with an address/ip of the download servers you're using) at least for the duration it takes for downloads to get stuck, and some more. Is there a slow or non-responding network node somewhere in that list?  Hit `d` to display the collected data in different ways (there are three or four modes).

Comment: @Hannu When I do it directly, there were no non-responding node. I've tried connecting to Jetbrain's DL server. and there were no issues even with docker.